# Is there an unambiguous composable representation of gimbal orientation?

Tags: rotations, angle

There are multiple ways to represent orientation:

- A rotation matrix,
- A quaternion,
- A triple of angles (Euler or Tait-Bryan).

Of these, the latter option has two possible representations for each orientation (I'm ignoring the gimbal lock cases here): e.g. for pitch-roll-yaw angle sequence, where we denote pitch with $p$, roll with $r$ and yaw with $y$, we have the equivalence:

$$(p,r,y)\equiv(p+\pi,\pi-r,y+\pi).\tag1$$

These two configurations, although representing the same orientation, can be distinct when applied to a real-life gimbal. E.g. one of the configurations may correspond to a camera suspended in the gimbal looking at the gimbal's armature, while the other would move the armature out of the camera's field of view.

While a matrix or a quaternion representations can be easily composed as successive rotations—by multiplication or conjugation respectively—the triple of angles representation is not as easily composable. One normally has to convert it to a matrix or quaternion form for this.

But if we convert the triple of angles to a matrix or a quaternion, we lose the additional degree of freedom: the binary choice between the two possible configurations of the gimbal. I.e. after we convert our triples of angles to e.g. matrices and multiply these matrices, we have to get a triple of angles back—and we can't recover the unique angles, since the problem simply has two solutions (again, ignoring gimbal lock).

I suppose the problem of unambiguous definition of the *unique* triple of angles of a composition of two rotations might be ill-defined in general. So I'll clarify what I think is the definition I'd like to use. Let there be two triples of pitch,roll,yaw: $(p_1,r_1,y_1)$ and $(p_2,r_2,y_2)$. The correct composite rotation of these, where the second triple gets applied to the initial object, and the first one rotates the whole system, is the composite $(2)$ where we can get the from the configuration with $\alpha=0$ to the one with $\alpha=1$ by a continuous change of the resulting angles with the change in $\alpha$.

$$(p_{\text{result}},r_{\text{result}},y_{\text{result}})=(p_1,r_1,y_1)*(\alpha p_2,\alpha r_2,\alpha y_2).
\tag2$$

**Question**: is there any representation of rotations that would let me compose two rotations initially given as triples of angles, "automatically" preserving the continuity of resulting angles as described above?

Comment: If you restrict one of the angles to $\pm \pi/2$ you will get a unique representation.  Usually it is the second angle.  Composition should only be done with matrices or quaternions... that is why they are so powerful.

Comment: @Tpofofn if I restrict an angle, I'll throw away some of possible physical configurations of the gimbal. In general, its sub-gimbals may be asymmetric in construction, which will make the different representations distinct.

Comment: If you are concerned with continuity, you could track the middle angle (what I call pitch) and let it exceed the $[-\pi/2,+\pi/2]$ interval.  How to handle this back and forth with matrices and quaternions is a little involved and I don't have time to go into detail right now, but in the calculations of one of the angles you normally square some of the values and take a square root.  It is there that the restriction creeps into the conversion.  You could look into the math and work it out from your specific conventions.  I could expand on this but not before the weekend.

Comment: @Tpofofn I've made something like a tracker that looks how the composite PRY angles change while stepping no more than 45° at a time in each angle, and chooses the result of matrix-to-angles transformation that are closer to the previous values. This does seem to let me ensure continuity. But I thought there may be some neater mathematical trick that would let me avoid this "dynamics simulation" approach.

Comment: that is a good approach.  Have you encountered the situation where your pitch exceeds $\pm \pi/2$?

Comment: @Tpofofn yes, it's the working configuration of my gimbal (note that its order of angles is pitch-roll-yaw, not the usual roll-pitch-yaw). The configuration when the camera doesn't look "into itself" is $p\in[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$. I don't think I've ever traversed the gimbal lock configuration though (it's numerically improbable).

Comment: Which axes are pitch, roll and yaw associated with?  Also, is your outermost joint in the pitch or yaw axis?  Is your sequence Z-Y-X with respect to body fixed axes?

Comment: The outermost is yaw. The innermost is pitch. The sequence is Y, X, Z. But all this seems to be quite irrelevant to the general issue of this question. If there's a suitable representation, then it'd be applicable to any order of axes (after all, it's only naming), and also even if we switch from Tait-Bryan to Euler angles.

Comment: Yes, but the thing with Euler angles is that there are so many variations, it is difficult to be specific.  Your conversion from matrices or quaternions back to Euler angles includes one angle (roll in your case) that is something like $arcsin(\cdot)$.  We normally chose the value to be in $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$.  You could just as easily choose the range $[\pi/2, 3\pi/2]$.  That choice also affects how you compute the remaining two angles.  You have to work it out for your specific case.

Comment: @Tpofofn the problem is not how to choose the good final angles. It's how to determine _actual_ final angles (after a composition, with the continuity in mind).